# Mongodump and mongorestore; field not found

Tags: mongodb, database

I'm trying to dump a database from another server (this works fine), then restore it on a new server (this does not work fine).

I first run:

```
mongodump --host -d
```

This creates a folder `dump/db` which contains all of the bson documents.

Then in the dump folder, I'm running:

```
mongorestore -d dbname db
```

This works and iterates through the files, but I get this error on `dbname.system.users`

```
Wed May 23 02:08:05 { key: { _id: 1 }, ns: "dbname.system.users", name: "_id_" }
Error creating index dbname.system.usersassertion: 13111 field not found, expected type 16
```

Any ideas how to resolve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Any chance the source and destination are different versions?

In any case, to get around this, restore the collections individually using the -c flag to the target DB and then build the indexes afterward.  The system collection is the one used for indexes, so it is fairly easy to recreate - try it last once everything else has been restore, and if it still fails you can always just recreate the relevant indexes.

Comment: Yeah, had similar problem with trying to `mongorestore` to MongoHQ from local. Downgraded local via `brew` and no more errors.

Comment: By version do you mean database version, or some kind of schema version?  Does the version of `mongorestore` run locally matter, or do just the versions from and to need to be in sync?

Comment: I meant database version and tools version.  There have been some changes to the tools (mongodump/restore/import etc.) over the revisions.  They have added to what is dumped out and how it is stored, particularly when it comes to meta data and indexes which can lead to problems on occasion if you mix and match the tools and the database. Generally it is a good idea to be dumping and restoring with (for example) the 2.2 version of the tools if you are using the 2.2 version of the database

Answer (score 11):

If it realy different versions, use `--noIndexRestore` option. And create all index after that.

Answer (score 3):

The issue could also caused by this bug in older versions of Mongo (In my case it was 2.0.8):

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-7181

Basically, you get `13111 field not found, expected type 16` error when it should actually be prompting you to enter your authentication details.

And example of how I fixed it:

```
root@precise64:/# mongorestore /backups/demand/ondemand.05-24-2013T114223/
connected to: 127.0.0.1
[REDACTED]
Fri May 24 11:48:15      going into namespace [test.system.indexes]
Fri May 24 11:48:15 { key: { _id: 1 }, ns: "test.system.users", name: "_id_" }
Error creating index test.system.usersassertion: 13111 field not found, expected type 16
# Error when not giving username and password

root@precise64:/# mongorestore -u fakeuser -p fakepassword /backups/demand/ondemand.05-24-2013T114223/
connected to: 127.0.0.1
[REDACTED]
Fri May 24 11:57:11 /backups/demand/ondemand.05-24-2013T114223/test/system.users.bson
Fri May 24 11:57:11      going into namespace [test.system.users]
1 objects found
# Works fine when giving username and password! :)
```

Hope that helps anyone who's issue doesn't get fixed by the previous 2 replies!

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen if you are trying to mongorestore into MongoDB 2.6+ and the dump you are trying to restore contains a `system.users` table in any database other than admin.  In MongoDB 2.2 and 2.4 the `system.users`collections could occur in any database.  The auth schema migration associated with MongoDB 2.6 moved all users into the `system.users` table in the admin database, but left behind the `system.users` tables in the other databases (MongoDB 2.6 just ignores these).  This seems to cause this assertion when importing into MongoDB 2.6.